# how to ask run time permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in android

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to get run time permission in  android for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
below code i have tried to ask run time permission but i am not getting permission

```
 private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)}, 1);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)}, 1);
            }
           
        }
        return false ;
    }
    }
```

I am checking this code in Android 13 os version . Please help me what i am doing wrong how i can get run time permission in android 13 for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE .

Comment: The code you provided looks correct. Make sure you have added the permission to your manifest.xml file. Also, when you are requesting the permission, you should provide a rationale for why you need this permission. You can do this by overriding the onRequestPermissionsResult() method in your activity and adding a call to shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() to check if you should show a rationale for the permission request. If you should, you should show an explanation to the user (e.g. via a dialog) and then call requestPermissions() again.

Comment: @Mech Thanks for answer yes i have provide same  i am making sure i have given permission in android manifest file also but i don't know why i am not getting permission dialog in android 13 ?

Comment: @Mech I have updated code can you please check where i am doing wrong .

Comment: Requesting WRITE permission is not requesting FINE permission. What do you need?

Comment: I need Write external permission so that i can save file in SD Card

Comment: Then why did you post -wrong- code for FINE?

Comment: But removable micro SD Cards are read only since Android Kitkat. So that permission will not help you. For an Android 13 device you should not request WRITE permission at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Please read the android developer app target android 13 permission.

If your app targets Android 13 or higher and needs to access media files that other apps have created, you must request one or more of the following granular media permissions instead of the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission:

**Type of media Permission to request
Images and photos:- READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
Videos:-READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
Audio files:-READ_MEDIA_AUDIO**

[Android Developer Page Link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13)

On your AndroidManifest file add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

In your activity ask the user this way

```
private val permissionstorage = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
    )
} else {
    arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    )
}
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: Thanks @Pritesh Parmar for helping i have just one question do we need runtime permission for this or simply we define these in android manifest file

Comment: Yes needed run time permission for users.

Comment: i am trying to download image and store in sd card but due to permission its not downloading can you please help me android 13  which permission is required to download image ?

Comment: you need to require READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission.

Comment: but when we apply this permission no permission asking also  image is not downloading at all

Comment: I have updated my answer please read it. I hope You can easily understand.

Comment: Thanks let me try your update answer